# bundle.js file leads to maximum stack exceeded

Tags: angularjs, angular

When I run npm run build first time my Angular 2 app works. However if I stop npm run build and later restart again

[image: enter image description]

and million more line like this

I delete bundle.js file it works without running npm run build it just does not show the work. It only shows loading...

when I run npm run build than again the error

Comment: could you have a recursive function calling itself somewhere?

Comment: I found out that atom typescript add-on is creating extra js files. it is leading to the issue that I am having. Anyways thank you for  your time!